# How to use lodash library in snowflake?

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lodash

Is possible to use lodash in snowflake? Because, i couldn't find any example for lodash library integration with snowflake. If anyone worked on this, could you please share the steps of how to use lodash library in snowflake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking if you can use the Lodash libraries in Snowflake Javascript stored procedures then the answer is no: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-introduction.html#libraries